# transporter.sendMail is not a function, I have used node.js with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

This is my `app.js` file this code seems to be correct, but gets an `transporter.sendMail is not a function` error.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
        
links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        links.forEach(ele => ele.classList.remove('active'));
        link.classList.add('active');
    })
})

// contact form
const contactBtn = document.querySelector('.contact-btn');
const firstName = document.querySelector('.first-name');
const lastName = document.querySelector('.last-name');
const email = document.querySelector('.email');
const msg = document.querySelector('.message');

contactBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(firstName.value.length && 
        lastName.value.length && email.value.length && msg.value.length ){
            fetch('/mail', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    firstname: firstName.value,
                    lastname: lastName.value,
                    email: email.value,
                    msg: msg.value,
                    
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    alert(data);
                })
            })
        }
})
```

This is my `server.js` file. What is the error in this file? I have trying this since few hours, but not getting the output. I'm a beginner and trying this project of sending mail using `nodemailer`.

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

var firstname = '#';
firstname.substring(1); 
var lastname = '#';
lastname.substring(1); 
var email = '#';
email.substring(1); 
var msg = '#';
msg.substring(1); 
var transporter = '#';
transporter.substring(1);

dotenv.config();
let initialPath = path.join(__dirname, "public");
let app = express();

app.use(express.static(initialPath));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(initialPath, "index.html"));
})

app.post('/mail', (req, res) => {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, msg } = req.body;

    
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        }
    })
})

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'yyy@gmail.com',
    to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Portfolio',
    text: `First name: ${firstname}, \nLast name: ${lastname}, 
    \nEmail: ${email}, \nMessage: ${msg}`
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, result) => {
    if (err){
    console.log(err)
        res.json('Oops error occurred')
    } else{
        res.json('thanks for emailing me');
    }
})

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('listening....');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the transporter inside of the post callback but referencing it outside the callback, therefore the transporter variable is referencing the global `var transporter = '#';` instead of the actual email transporter.

*That explains why the sendMail function does not exist because the transporter is a string and not a object.*

Below I put a comment on where to put the send mail code.

```
app.post('/mail', (req, res) => {
   const { firstname, lastname, email, msg } = req.body;
     
   let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD
            
        }
    })
    // Put the send email config here
})
```

This is how the final result should be.

```
app.post('/mail', (req, res) => {
    const { firstname, lastname, email, msg } = req.body;

    
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD
        
        }
    })

    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'yyy@gmail.com',
        to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Portfolio',
        text: `First name: ${firstname}, \nLast name: ${lastname}, 
        \nEmail: ${email}, \nMessage: ${msg}`
    }
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, result) => {
        if (err){
        console.log(err)
            res.json('Opps error occured')
        } else{
            res.json('thanks for e-mailing me');
        }
    })
})

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('listening....');
})
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Making use of a Javascript linter would have shown you your issue. Also to keep track of brackets I use a plugin in vscode called **Bracket Pair Colorizer 2**. Makes things much easier.

Comment: Thank u so much Trevor, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it occurred because I've made a spell mistake `transporter.sendmail` instead of `transporter.sendMail`.
Hope you got your mistake

Answer (score 0):

I came here unable to find the solution to a somewhat different issue I was having with the same error. I was exporting the transporter in error.

```
module.exports = transporter
```

which revealed nested transporters at the end.
in order to fix this export transporter in object as below

```
module.exports = {transporter}
```